# How to use webkeys() to insert text in a webview and trigger onChange event with Espresso

Tags: javascript, android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have a webview containing an input field and a button below it (webview is 3rd party code)
When I open the view on my phone, as soon as I insert a digit into the field,
the button changes color and is enabled.

The input field is

```
 <input type="tel" name="input" id="input" class="inputbox"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="number" value="">
```

When I run my automatic test with Espresso I can put text into the field but the button is not enabled

```
 onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "input"))
            .perform(clearElement())
            .perform(DriverAtoms.webKeys("22222222"))
            .perform(webClick())
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "continueButton"))
            .perform(webClick());
```

Firefox inspector shows there is an event listener for the onChange event whose listener I suppose is this one:

```
            function(e) {
          e.persist();
          var t = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
          d((function(a) {
            return Object(c.a)(Object(c.a)({}, a), {}, Object(M.a)({}, e.target.name, t.test(e.target.value) ? e.target.value : e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")))
          })), e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").length > 0 ? (j(!1), b("primary"), k(""), R("")) : (b("primary disabled"), k("hidden"), R("paddingTop20"))
        }
```

So I tried triggering the onchange with no luck:

```
   onWebView().forceJavascriptEnabled().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID,    "input"))
            .perform(clearElement())
            .perform(webClick())
            .perform(DriverAtoms.webKeys("22222222"))
            .perform(webClick())
            .perform(SimpleAtom("function(elem) {\n" +
                    "var e = document.createEvent('Event');\n" +
                    "e.initEvent('change', false, true);\n" +
                    "elem.dispatchEvent(e);}"))
            .perform(webClick())
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "continueButton"))
            .perform(webClick());
```

If I insert numbers with keyboard continueButton becomes enabled and I can click it and proceed with the text, but using webkeys() does not work.
How can I trigger the onChange event (or whatever event is needed) similar like using the keyboard and perform the webclick() with Espresso?

Comment: Could you show the form's HTML ?

Comment: @ElJackiste hi this is the form <input type="tel" name="name" id="name" class="inpubox" autocomplete="off" placeholder="numberr" value="">  (I cant paste the whole page b/c it is not our code)

Comment: You said you could put text into the field with espresso. In your example, the form's ID doesn't match your test, you put `input` but your ID is `name`. Also, why did you perform a `webClick()` after `webKeys("222");` ? Did you tried to make it wait / sleep after `webKeys("222");` ?

Comment: @ElJackiste sorry for not being precise enough, i modified the names b/c they have a name associated with the code's creator. I will modify my first post to add the information in a more clear way. I had tried different combinations with webclick() and clear() to see if there was a difference, it didn't help. The only thing that worked was this: document.getElementById('continueButton').className='button primary' That is. changing the type of the continueButton to make it enabled, but it was just a visual trick, it is like the form can't see the number that I put in there unless I use keyboard

Comment: @ElJackiste do u suggest to use a thread sleep?

Comment: Yes maybe a thread sleep to let it have time to fire event. I am not an Android developer and can't test anything right now. I will check tomorrow at home. Maybe you can try the tag `android-testing` to get more help.

Comment: Could you show me the HTML button ?
Are you sure of the event triggered ? Did you tried `input` event ?

Comment: hello. the button is as below:  <button class="button primary disabled" id="continueButton" type="button"><span class="button_label">number</span><i class="spinner"></i></button>

once a number is entered:

<button class="button primary" id="continueButton" type="button"><span class="button_label">number</span><i class="spinner"></i></button>

Comment: Ok did you tried to change your `change`event by `input` event or other event ?

Comment: yes, i tried other events, but the behaviour is the same: nothing happens

Comment: Ok, I don't have android environment with me and can't reproduce your problem. I will let you know if i found something.

Comment: Do you have the url page you are trying to test ?

Comment: Did you try to select the span with `button_label` class instead of `continueButton` to click on it ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a Node.js web server and I downloaded Android Studio to make some tests. Here is the HTML page I tested based on your informations :

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input"),
    button = document.getElementById("continueButton"),
    result = document.getElementById("result"),
    label = document.querySelector('.button_label');

input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    result.innerHTML = "click success!";
  });
  
  button.classList.remove("disabled");
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form onclick="event.preventDefault();">
  <input type="tel" name="input" id="input" class="inputbox"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="number" value="">
  <button class="disabled" id="continueButton"><span class="button_label">number</span><i class="spinner"></i></button>
</form>

<p type="text" name="result" id="result"></p>
```

I used your Espresso tests and **both of them work fine** for me.
Simple version which works also :

```java
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "input"))
               .perform(DriverAtoms.webKeys("22222222"))
               .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "continueButton"))
               .perform(webClick());
```

To me, your code is good. It works in my local computer.

Now, it is difficult to debug without the third party webview to reproduce exactly the problem. Maybe it comes from the event which is not good. `webKeys` could triggered the wrong event which is not listenned by the webapp. Also, to your second try to trigger event manually, it is probably not the `change` event that you should use because `change` doesn't get triggered by keyboard which is the case in your situation.

Another explanation could be that you don't choose the good elements to click on : `.button_label` instead of `continueButton` ? Indeed, if you replace in my example `button.addEventListener` by `label.addEventListener`, the Espresso test won't work anymore, but it will work if you do it manually with your keyboard.

To investigate more, I need the URL of the page load in the webview.

Little note, your way of firing event is deprecated. You should use the constructor :

```js
var event = new Event('change');
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: I given up. There is no way to work it with my webview. It works instead with other normal form, like yours and other links I tried

Comment: Ok ;) If you want you can still give me the url load in your webview, i will check it.